# Replace NULL values in Joins

Tags: sql, join, null

Having some hard time replacing Null values.

Screen capture from database tryouts

[image]

Dataset:

```
Computer -  (Compid, Make, Model, Myear)
Employee - (Id, Ename, Doj, Salary, Bonus, Dept, Designation, Manager, Compid)
```

My code:

```
SELECT E.Ename , E.Dept, C.MODEL FROM Employee E 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Computer C ON E.Compid = C.Compid
```

Result not showing any nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`

```
SELECT E.Ename , E.Dept, coalesce(C.MODEL,'Not allocated') as model 
FROM Employee E LEFT OUTER JOIN Computer C ON E.Compid = C.Compid
```